# Detecting "animationend" event of a chained animation set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my CSS, in which, three keyframes are bound together to make a chain animation

```
#anim-div{
    -webkit-animation-name    : mpbar-anim-page1, mpbar-anim-page2, mpbar-anim-page3;
    animation-name            : mpbar-anim-page1, mpbar-anim-page2, mpbar-anim-page3;
    -webkit-animation-delay   : 0s, 0.7s, 1.4s;
    animation-delay           : 0s, 0.7s, 1.4s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-duration        : 0.7s;
}
```

Is it possible to detect **animationend** event of the whole set?
when I try, it detects **animationend** for each individual keyframes (ending up firing 3 events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the number of animations is unknown and the name of the final animation is also unknown, you could achieve this by using [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to read the animations into an array. Then, when the `animationend` event fires, increment a variable and execute the code you wish when the value of that variable equals the length of the array, like so:

```js
var div=document.querySelector("div"),
    style=window.getComputedStyle(div),
    animation=style.getPropertyValue("animation-name")||style.getPropertyValue("-moz-animation-name")||style.getPropertyValue("-webkit-animation-name"),
//  Delete unneeded prefixed properties above 
    count=animation?animation.split(",").length:0,
    ended=0;
div.addEventListener("animationend",function(){
  ended++;
  if(ended===count){
//  Your code here
    console.log(ended+" animations completed.");
  }
},0);
```

```css
div{
  animation:x 1s ease-in-out,y 1s ease-in-out 1s,z 1s ease-in-out 2s;
  background:#000;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
@keyframes x{to{transform:rotatex(180deg);}}
@keyframes y{to{transform:rotatey(180deg);}}
@keyframes z{to{transform:rotatez(180deg);}}
/* Housekeeping */
body,html{height:100%;}
body{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that the *animationend event* of the whole set is actually the *animationend* event of the animation that **ends last** (in our case, the third animation).

So in the *animationend* event that is binded to our element, we need to detect the name of the animation that has just ended and check if it matches the third animation.
We can acces the `originalEvent` object and get the `animationName` property.

Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#anim-div').on(animationEvent, function(e){
         var animationName = e.originalEvent.animationName;
         if (animationName == 'mpbar-anim-page3') {
             console.log('"' + animationName + '" animation has finished');
        }
    });

});
```

I've used the variable `animationEvent` to get the correct name of the animationend event (some browsers may require a prefixed version). You need to put the folllowing code **before** the one above:

```
function whichAnimationEvent(){
    var t,
        el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

    var animations = {
        "animation"      : "animationend",
        "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
        "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
        "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
    }

    for (t in animations){
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
            return animations[t];
        }
    }
}

var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();
```

I've also put the complete code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/psxxbp2y/.

Tested in *Firefox*, *Chrome* and *Opera*.

Comment: useful trick, but is it possible to do the same without knowing the animation name?

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try

Comment: Good solution for when the animations are known. However, I'd suggest editing the end of your first paragraph to make it clearer that it's the name of the animation that *ends* last that should be used, rather than the one that is declared last.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Shaggy. I've just corrected the answer.